# Checking for negative numbers in Array and re-prompting for correct input

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

The idea is to create an average for money made in a week by day and my average must be calculated in a method that is called in the main method. That is the easy part, but the part I'm stuck on is if a number less than zero is entered it should give me an error message and re-prompt the user for a better value. I'm not looking for a handout here just for someone to tell me what I've been doing wrong if it is simple and easy or a pointer in the right direction.

```
import java.util.*;

public class weeklyAveragesClient2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)//output averages in format
    {
        averageCash();
    }

    public static double averageCash()//use array and loop to calculate weekly average
    {
        double [] cashMoney;
        cashMoney = new double[7];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = 0;
        String s = "ERROR";

        while (j < 7)
        {     
            double num = cashMoney[j]; 

            if (num == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error please enter a number > 0");
                num = j;
                cashMoney[j] = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            else if(num > 0)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter an amount for day " + (j+1) +": ");
                cashMoney[j] = scan.nextDouble();
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: negative number please enter a number >       0");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Calculating...");

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cashMoney.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + cashMoney[i];
        }
        double average = sum / (double)cashMoney.length;
        System.out.println("Average: " + average);
        return average;
    }//end averageCash
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments that will hopefully provide food for thought.

```
// This will *always* be zero at first because you haven't called scan.nextDouble() yet 
// and zero is the default value. So when you run the program, it will output "Error 
// please enter a number > 0" before doing anything else
if (num == 0) {
    System.out.println("Error please enter a number > 0");
    num = j;
    cashMoney[j] = scan.nextDouble();
} else if (num > 0) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an amount for day " + (j + 1) + ": ");
    cashMoney[j] = scan.nextDouble();
    j++;
} else {
    // If we get into this state, the user will never be invited to enter 
    // another number, since the last entered number was negative, so 
    // num == 0 is false, and
    // num > 0 is false, so
    // we'll end up back here. In fact, you'll enter an infinite loop and
    // this message will be printed over and over again.
    System.out.println("Error: negative number please enter a number >       0");
    // cashMoney[j] = scan.nextDouble(); // <-- try prompting the user again
}
```

Please also consider indenting your code correctly. It will greatly increase readability. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you can select Source > Format.